# For FDA certification hipaa is mandatory?

Tags: compliance, hipaa

I am working on a medical device. I want to FDA certification for it. 
The device is having ePHI (protected health information).
So is it mandatory to have HIPAA compliance for FDA approval?

Comment: I don't think you will get an answer here. I would contact FDA if they can't give you an answer try contacting U.S. Department of Health & Human Services.

Comment: This link was at the top of my google search for your question: http://www.fdalawblog.com/2013/08/articles/legislation/hipaahitech-compliance-strategies-for-medical-device-manufacturers/

Comment: What research have you done on your question?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the FDA will require HIPAA compliance for any device that uses PHI -- but, as has been noted in the comments to your question, the FDA will be the sole authority on its own requirements. This question-and-answer site is designed to provide helpful guidance -- but what you need is a legal opinion.

That said, even if you find that HIPAA compliance is not mandatory for the device you are working on, **your only wise choice is to build on a foundation of HIPAA compliance anyway**. This is especially important since you're already working with PHI. (And it would still be important even if you weren't, to allow for growth of your product.)

Comment: You will find the FDA's answer in the link posted by schroeder as a comment to the question.

Comment: The medical device in dealing with PHI but still it is starting phase of this device. I just need to do FDA certification. So is it mandatory to have HIPAA for FDA approval?